# Cannot carry SESSION variables across pages

Tags: php, html

I am having trouble with session variables. I created the session variable on page1.php and then tried to display it on page2.php, but it didn't work. I made sure to add session_start(); at the beginning of the page so that's not the problem.

Here is my code for page1.php

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>

<title>website</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

<?php 
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])) {

$_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];

}

?>


 </head>

 <body id="body">

<form action="page2.php" method="post">

<input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

</body>

</html>
```

Here is my code for page2.php

```
<?php

 session_start();


?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>


<title>website</title>
<link rel="icon" href="icon.png">
<link rel="stylsheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>

<body id="body">

Your username is: <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `if(!isset($_POST["submit"]))` I think, that shouldn't be negated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### You have several things wrong

**1. If statement**
The code will only excecute **IF** $_POST['submit'] isn't initialized.

To fix this, you need to remove your '!' before is isset();

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
}
```

**2. Your POST variable goes to page2.php**

You need to add this to page2.php:

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
}
```

You just had the code in the wrong place. So close.

Comment: Thanks, Mark Mueller.

Comment: @koolaidguy since this was the answer could you click the ✓ on my answer. I'm glad it worked!

Comment: Except that page1 will not receive any $_POST at all as it is not the script that gets sent the $_POST

Comment: MARK Mueller. I can't give you the ✓ because you made a comment. If you make an answer I will definitely give you the ✓

Comment: @koolaidguy the answer is what we are typing under.  Its next to the giant 0 with the 2 arrows.

Answer (score 1):

`$_POST['username']` will not be available in `page1.php` it will only be available in `page2` as that is the page that responds to the FORM being submitted.

Similiarly `$_POST["submit"]` will not be available in `page1`

> Add this while testing to the top of your script, then even if you are developing on a site configured for a LIVE environment you will see errors like

**Undefined index** which should be being sent from `page1.php`

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 
ini_set('log_errors',1); 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Comment: You've been faster than me :/

Answer (score 1):

in page1.php you have

```
// v------ wrong logic?
if(!isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
}
```

and then

```
<!--              v---------- page2.php -->
<form action="page2.php" method="post">

<input type="username" id="username" name="username" placeholder="Username">
<input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

That means, when you are submitting the form, you'll be redirected to page2.php, that doesn't handle the form datas `$_POST`.

You might want to place this piece of code in page2.php :

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $_SESSION["username"] = $_POST["username"];
}
```

---

Note :

Top of your pages, you have :

```
<?php 
session_start();

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
```

As you can notice, there will be some characters (a vertical whitespace) rendered **before** the `<!DOCTYPE html>` that will activate the [quirks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode) mode on some browsers. Make sure the doctype is the first line in your page.

Comment: But we are both correct :)